# How to send xml flex to php via post method in <mx:httpservice >?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, air, flash

i created xml in flex after that creation i post to php via http service  but when i add like xml in http service  flex throws error msg like Error #1096: XML parser failure: Unterminated element." 
What did i worng ? How to send xml data flex to php ? plz refer me

```
<mx:HTTPService id="createxml"  method="POST" url="http://####/admin/?do=storebettingdetails" useProxy="false"></mx:HTTPService>var xm:XML = new XML("**********"); ------ adding child node -- Thend attached xml to service like createxml.request=xm;
```

createxml.send();

Answer (score 2):

in script make your xml variable

```
[Bindable]
private var xml : XML = new XML("xml code");
```

and in mxml, on your httpservice component make:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="createxml"
         method="post"
         url="http://....../?do=storebettingdetails">
    <mx:request>
        <myxml>{this.xml}</myxml>
    </mx:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

you will get the xml in php as $_POST['myxml']